# sql insert binary data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using sql server r2 2008

i want to insert a binary data using a query

i tried this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[User]
(GSM, SIM, [Password], SessionID, [type])
VALUES
("1", "1", "1", "1", '0x00')
```

but i got an error in the "0x00"

what should i do please?

This is the error

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name '1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name '1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name '1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name '1'.
```

Comment: Simply 0x00 not '0x00'

Comment: Remove the quotes, 0x indicates a binary literal

Comment: @PeterRing when i did your soluton, i got the error that i put in the questoni

Comment: @AlexK. when i did your solution, i got the error that i put in the question,

Comment: Single quotes here -> `("1", "1", "1", "1", 0x00)`

Comment: You either need to use single quotes instead of double quotes around each value (e.g. `'1'` instead of `"1"`), or use `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;` to allow double quotes for string literal, or if they are integers remove the quotes completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont need ''.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[User]
(GSM, SIM, [Password], SessionID, [type])
VALUES
('1', '1', '1', '1', 0x00)
```

Comment: +1 to you, i will accept your answer after 8 minutes

Answer (score 0):

like this..

```
INSERT INTO
    [MyDatabase].[dbo].[tblPicture]
    ( Name, Branch, Age, Image )

    (
        SELECT 'a','amd',1,*
        FROM OPENROWSET
            (BULK N'c:\image.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB)
        AS Picture
    )
```